# SATA compliance test

Tags: testing, high-speed, specifications, sata, compliance

Is there anyone familiar with the SATA interface compliance?
I'm curious about the testing method.

For TX test, there are PHY/TSG/OOB test items.
And, there are BIST-L and BIST-TSA mode defined in SATA spec.

- What mode should be used when testing TX? and how?

The other question is for RX test.

- Should we set the controller to BIST-L mode when testing RX?
  Use the data generated from JBERT, and loopback it to JBERT?